# Can I use different data types in a general linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r, self-study, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I've become quite familiar with linear mixed effects models but I'm not very certain about their General counterparts.

I have a data set which looks like the following:

```
      PP Age Gender       Education    Student Familiarity         ID Correct
5   pp1  22   Male          PostGr    Student         Yes widgetTime       1
6   pp1  22   Male          PostGr    Student         Yes  racePlace       1
7   pp1  22   Male          PostGr    Student         Yes  emilyName       1
8  pp10  24   Male BachelorsDegree NotStudent         Yes  emilyName       1
9  pp10  24   Male BachelorsDegree NotStudent          No  farmSheep       1
10 pp10  24   Male BachelorsDegree NotStudent         Yes   dirtHole       1
```

Participants (`PP`) were asked to answer seven questions (`ID`), where their answer was `Correct` (1) or incorrect (0). For every question, they were asked if they had ever seen that question before (`Familiarity` = Yes, No). Within the data set, I also have demographics such as `Age`, `Gender` (2 levels), `Education` (3 levels) and `Student` (2 levels).

Particularly, I want to know whether being Familiar (`Familiarity`) with the question (`ID`) would lead to more `Correct` answers. My first assumption was to use a Chi Square (`Familiarity` x `Correct`) but I was told it was not the best measure as, if I recall, it assumes independence. I was told a general linear mixed effects model using R's `glmer` function would help, as I can also include random effects (`PP` and `ID`). I know that a GLMM is more suited for this data as the DV is binomial (0,1).

My question is: can I use all the predictors (contrast coded as -0.5, 0.5 (except for `Education`, which is 1, 1, -2 & 1, -1, 0)) in my `glmer` formula, even though `Age` is numeric? I'm used to only using categorical variables in my `lmer` functions. I assume my formula would be as follows:

```
glmer.model=glmer(Correct~Familiarity + Age + Gender + Education + Student + (1|PP) + (1|ID), family = "binomial", DemoScore)
```

Should I also be factoring the Familiarity variable (and therefore contrast code) or convert it into `0` and `1`?

I initially thought summing the `Correct` scores for each PP would make more sense, but this does not as `Familiarity` is for question-by-question.

Any clarification would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's no problem mixing categorical and continuous predictors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I use all the predictors (contrast coded as -0.5, 0.5 (except for Education, which is 1, 1, -2 & 1, -1, 0)) in my glmer formula, even though Age is numeric?

Yes, there are no particular concerns when including different types of variables in a glmm. From this point of view there is no difference to other types of regression model.

> I assume my formula would be as follows:

```
> glmer.model=glmer(Correct ~ Familiarity + Age + Gender + Education + Student + (1|PP) + (1|ID), family = "binomial", DemoScore)
```

This model seems to make sense. If all participants saw all questions then you have a crossed design and `(1|PP) + (1|ID)` is the right way to specify the random structure.

> Should I also be factoring the Familiarity variable (and therefore contrast code) or convert it into 0 and 1?

It's not completely clear what you mean. From your data listed in the question `Familiarity` seems to be a factor with `Yes` and `No` levels. This will be treated the same as if you recode it to 0/1.

> I initially thought summing the Correct scores for each PP would make more sense, but this does not as Familiarity is for question-by-question.

That's correct. Summing or averaging the scores would lose important informaton.